# Linked List: What does (!elem) mean and (!(elem = *stack)) in the following code?

Tags: c, list, stack

```
typedef struct Element 
{
    struct Element *next;
    void *data;
} Element;
```

In the pop function, what does the line (!(elem = *stack)) mean?

```
bool pop( Element **stack, void **data )
{
    Element *elem;
    if (!(elem = *stack)) return false;

    *data = elem->data;
    *stack = elem->next;
    delete elem;
    return true;
}
```

In the push function, what does the line (!elem) mean?

```
bool push( Element **stack, void *data )
{
    Element *elem = new Element;
    if(!elem) return false;

    elem->data = data;
    elem->next = *stack;
    *stack = elem;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It means if *stack is 0, return false.  In the push function, it means if elem was 0 i.e. not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, when a pointer is evaluated in boolean context, it evaluates to *true* if and only if it is not NULL. That is:

```
if (elem)
```

is exactly the same that:

```
if (elem != NULL)
```

And, conversely:

```
if (!elem)
```

equals:

```
if (elem == NULL)
```

About the oter case, an assignment expression, as a whole, evaluates to the assigned value. So `(elem = *stack)` evaluates to the assigned pointer. So:

```
if (!(elem = *stack)) return false;
```

is equivalent to:

```
elem = *stack;
if (elem == NULL) return false;
```

In this case, it is quite moot, but imagine that `elem` is instead a complicated expression:

```
if (!(array[a][b].element = *stack)) ...;
```

Here the ability to assign-and-use at the same time is quite handy.

You probably has seen this C feature, maybe without recognizing it, in code such as:

```
a = b = c = 0;
```

which is really parsed, because assignment is right associative) as:

```
a = (b = (c = 0));
```

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, this was a huge a help and cleared up my understanding immediately. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C crock.

In the old days, some really poor C textbooks taught that

```
if (!foo) { ... }
```

was more efficient than

```
if (foo != 0) {... }
```

This showed up in certain very influential places, and the crock became common.

```
if (!(elem = *stack)) { ... }
```

is more of the same.  You're setting elem equal to the top of the stack, and checking for NULL at the same time.